# Separate Columns with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with some problem data. For example, the table is as follow :

```
ID   NAME                            JOB
---  ---------------------------     ---------------
1    Peter                           Teacher
2    John                            Programmer
3    Tom**He is a Teacher  
4    Alan**He is a Accountant
```

The problem is some data has been correctly inserted but some hasn't. Now I want to execute an SQL in order to make the table looks like below :

```
ID   NAME                            JOB
---  ---------------------------     ---------------
1    Peter                           Teacher
2    John                            Programmer
3    Tom                             Teacher  
4    Alan                            Accountant
```

I am not familiar with SQL Statement so I can just think of using the following PHP Script to fix this problem.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT NAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE JOB = '' AND NAME LIKE '%He is a %'";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1)){
    $new_data = explode("**He is a ", $row1["NAME"]);
    $sql2 = "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET NAME = '".$data[0]."', JOB = '".$data[1]."' WHERE ID = '".$data["ID"]."'";
    mysql_query($sql2);
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better way for me to fix this problem with one or a few SQL Statement ? Thanks

Comment: So where job is blank/null then that job always corresponds to the last word in name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to break up the string, and apply all the changes in a single `update` statement:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    JOB = SUBSTRING_INDEX (name, '**He is a ', -1),
       name = SUBSTRING_INDEX (name, '**He is a ', 1),
WHERE  name LIKE '%**He is a %' AND
       (job IS NULL OR job = '') -- Just to be on the safe side
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE 
SET    NAME     = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NAME, '**He is a ', 1), ' ', -1),
       job      = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NAME, '**He is a ', 2), ' ', -1)
WHERE  NAME LIKE '%**He is a %'
```